# Barracuda 340 Load Balancer Won't Port Forward

Tags: networking, load-balancing

We have Barracuda 340 that we are trying to set up for load balancing across multiple servers, each with multiple applications running.  If I set up a service with the specific port we are sending UDP packets to, and one IP per Real Server (with the same port as the service) everything works fine.  Like the setup below:

```
1. Virtual IP: 192.168.14.10:20510
  1. Real Server #1: 192.168.13.4:20510
  2. Real Server #2: 192.168.13.5:20510
```

The problem is, if we try to run multiples of our applications on a single server, using different ports, it does not load balance (this does work without attempting to load balance).  It just ignores the one with the different port.  I can send traffic directly to that server port combo though, so I know it is listening.  That would be similar to the setup below:

```
1. Virtual IP: 192.168.14.10:20510
  1. Real Server #1: 192.168.13.4:20510
  2. Real Server #2: 192.168.13.4:20511
```

I also tried using different NICs on the same server, and binding the applications to the specific NICs.  When I do that, it completely ignores that server, and sends nothing to it.

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the 340 device?  Or if I am missing some simple settings that I've not found in the manual, yet.

Thanks for any assistance with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to have just been an issue with the device we are using...  Company bought it off Ebay, so... :)